# RV260W as Access Point

Tags: cisco, router, wireless, ieee-802.11, access-point

We recently upgraded to a proper firewall, with some help from this community, and are now looking to repurpose our RV260w as a wireless access point.  I tried already, but I was trying to use the WAN port, and I feel like perhaps it's never going to work that way.

Could I not connect the WAN port to anything, and just connect one of the LAN ports to my inside interface on the 5508-x (which is currently doing our routing and DHCP).  If at all possible I'd like the wireless clients connected via the RV260W to get DHCP addresses from the 5508-X.  This seems like it won't work.

I suppose another option would be to VLAN the RV260W traffic and join it on the 5508-X.  I don't know yet whether the RV260w will allow an RFC1918 address on the WAN port though.

Any thoughts on either of the options I laid out?

EDIT:
Basic rundown of final configuration:

1. NEW vlan on ASA to handle the "guest" wifi traffic at a lower security setting, with DHCP enabled for a different subnet
2. Added the VLAN to the trunk port between the 260w and the ASA on the switch.
3. Connected nothing to the WAN on the 260w, and added both wifi's (employee and guest) attached to the appropriate VLAN id's as configured on the ASA and the switch.
4. Pushed both VLANs out the trunk I made on LAN1 of the 260w.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WAP is a bridge. You would need to use any switch (bridge) interfaces, not router interfaces in the device. Router interfaces must be configured in different networks, but the switch interfaces configured for a VLAN are all in the same network.

The WAN interface is a router interface, and I do not think you can bridge it. You will need to use a switch interface in the router, and configure it to be in the same VLAN as the wireless interface.